# How to display detail data to modal using Next.js AppRouter?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm building an application to display data. I have a plan to add a facility to display detailed data via modal. Here are the components for displaying data:

```js
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const portofolios = [
    {
        id_portofolio: 1,
        title: "the title",
        description: "the description",
        category: { title: "the title of category" },
        author: {
            name: "the author name",
            role: "the author role",
            imageUrl: "the image url",
        },
    },
...
const Portofolio = () => {
    return (
        ...
        {portofolios.map((portofolio) => (
        <article key={portofolio.id_portofolio}>
        ...
        <a>{portofolio.category.title}</a>
        ...
        <Link href={`/portofolios/${portofolio.id_portofolio}`}><button>Read More</button></Link>
        ...
                
export default Portofolio
```

I have made a `"portofolios/[id_portofolio]"` folder under the `"app"` directory and I created a file in it named `"file.tsx"` shown below:

```js
"use client";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const ModalPortofolio = async ({ params }) => {
    ... I am using Modal

    <Dialog.Panel>
        <Dialog.Title>{title}</Dialog.Title>
        <div>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={closeModal}>Close!</button>
        </div>
    </Dialog.Panel>
    ...
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
Binding element 'params' implicitly has an `any` type. on async ({params}) line.
```

The modal is displaying but only showing the Close button. When I click the button I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you and I'm sorry about my English

Comment: Change `const ModalPortofolio = async ({ params }) => {` to `const ModalPortofolio = ({ params }) => {`